# Issue with approach to determine maximum distance a constant force can stretch a spring

Tags: spring

So I know the conventional way we determine the maximum distance a given constant force can stretch a spring, namely dividing the applied force by the spring constant, k. My issue is that I feel that would only tell us when the object attached to the spring would stop accelerating, not when it actually stops  (v = 0).

Can someone help me reason through this dilemna?

Answer (score 0):

If you hand a weight on a spring, and let it go, the system oscillates for a while, finally stopping somewhere near the midpoint of the excursions.  This is when the stretch is measured: when the system has stopped moving.

To take gravity out of the equation the standard spring test is performed by a machine which can measure the tension, and a system for slowly stretching the spring, as with a worm gear drive.

From this information one can find the spring constant for that spring design, and the limits to which the spring may be repeatedly stretch prior to failure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to estimate the spring constant k.

Stretch the spring in the horizontal direction with an ever-increasing force for which the rate of stretching of the spring is very small, and at various positions of the stretch reduce the force to where the spring is no longer stretching and record that force.  Then increase the force slightly until the string stretches some more, then reduce the force to where the spring is not longer stretching and record that force.  Repeat this process to obtain a set of $n$ measurements and record $(F(x_i), x_i)$ where $F(x_i)$ is the force to maintain the string stretched by an amount $x_i$ where $i = 1, 2, ...n$.  The average of the values $F(x_i)/x_i, for \enspace i = 1, 2, ...n$, is an estimate of the spring constant k.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you allow a falling object to stretch a spring, when the weight of the object exactly matches the restoring force of the spring the object will stop accelerating downwards and its velocity will be non-zero. As a result the object will overshoot, extending the spring further. The restoring force of the spring will increase causing the object to decelerate and eventually to rise upwards. As the spring compresses again, the restoring force will decrease until it becomes less than gravity and the object will once more accelerate downwards. The object will oscillate up and down around the equilibrium point, where the restoring force equals the weight, but gradually frictional forces will dissipate all the energy and the object will come to rest.